# Renaming files generated by Flutter in release

Tags: windows, flutter, dll, exe, obfuscation

Is there a way to rename the files generated in the release mode in Flutter Windows? For example, renaming the dll files, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the executable file name and many params...
But the dlls files you don't.

Exemple,
For change the exe name , in windows/runner/main.cpp , search by

```
if (!window.Create(L"your_app_name", origin, size))
```

and change to name that you want:

```
if (!window.Create(L" new_exe_name", origin, size))
```

and change CMakeLists.txt too.
in `project(you_app_name LANGUAGES CXX)`
and `set(BINARY_NAME "your_app_name")`

in runner.rc you can change the version name(VERSION_AS_STRING), in line 72  and number(VERSION_AS_NUMBER) in line 66.
and other files params, line 92.

And finally in win32_windows.cpp you can change window parameter, like open maximized , or full screen etc.

So.. if you can open in full screen mode , change the line 139:

```
window_class, title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
```

to

```
window_class, title.c_str(), WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_MAXIMIZE,
```

and line 153

```
return ShowWindow(window_handle_, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

to

```
return ShowWindow(window_handle_, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

Comment: thx, nice summary but stuff u mention r not answer to the question except the fact that u believe we cannot change the dll file names! Still not sure how I can rename the files!

Comment: You cannot rename the dlls. Flutter use theses dlls to work. the question is, why? Why u want rename these files?
flutter build --release --obfuscate don't solve for u?

Comment: Because I dont want the exe file bundle immediately indicate that the program is made by Flutter. But currently some of the files including a dll file clearly has "Flutter" in it.

Comment: For what bro?!
In doc, flutter_windows.dll is a mandatory dll and cannot be renamed. But, you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74566661/10649115